# Getting data from SQL query where another column is unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can somebody help me with this query I am trying to write.

```
SELECT sku FROM product p where sku
not in(SELECT sku FROM price_adjustment p) and sku 
in (SELECT sku FROM searchable_product s where is_visible = 'T') and sku 
in (SELECT sku FROM channel_pricing c 
where offer_price > 10.00 and offer_price % 2 = 0) limit 5;
```

This query works fine but I also want to only pick skus where the search_prod_id is distinct. I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
SELECT sku, search_prod_id FROM product p where sku 
not in(SELECT sku FROM price_adjustment p) and sku 
in (SELECT sku FROM searchable_product s 
where is_visible = 'T') and sku in 
(SELECT sku FROM channel_pricing c 
where offer_price > 10.00 and offer_price % 2 = 0) and sku 
in (SELECT distinct search_prod_id from product p ) limit 5;
```

When I run that I can see the search_prod_id is the same for each sku.

Can somebody tell me what  I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to find  sku for which there is only one searc_prod_id?

Comment: Whe nyou say "only pick skus where the search_prod_id is distinct". Do you really mean "only pick skus where the search_prod_id only appears once"?

Comment: one search product id can have multiple skus. when the query runs i want 5 skus that all belong to a different search_prod_id.

Comment: ok.. you are selecting from Product, so do you want to see a Product more than once if it is related to different skus s?

Comment: I want to see 5 distinct skus from 5 distinct search_prod_id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the `search_prod_id` to be different by grouping them

```
SELECT MAX(sku) sku, search_prod_id 
FROM   product p 
WHERE  sku NOT IN(SELECT sku 
                  FROM   price_adjustment) 
  AND  sku IN (SELECT sku 
               FROM   searchable_product
               WHERE  is_visible = 'T') 
  AND  sku IN (SELECT sku 
               FROM   channel_pricing c 
               WHERE  offer_price > 10.00 
                 AND  offer_price % 2 = 0)
GROUP BY search_prod_id
LIMIT 5;
```

also in your query you're checking sku against search_prod_id, every match it's just luck (bad luck IMO)

```
sku in (SELECT distinct search_prod_id from product p )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query it may work,

```
'SELECT sku FROM product p where search_prod_id in(
SELECT DISTINCT search_prod_id ,sku FROM product p where sku not in(
SELECT sku FROM price_adjustment p) and sku in (
SELECT sku FROM searchable_product s 
where is_visible = 'T') and sku in 
(SELECT sku FROM channel_pricing c 
where offer_price > 10.00 and offer_price % 2 = 0) limit 5;'
```

Comment: I can't get this query to run it just says there is an error.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in (SELECT sku, search_prod_id FROM product p where sku not in(SELECT sku FROM p' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I have the syntax correct, but something similar. I used a GROUPING in the last AND clause to only give search_prod_id s where there is only one!

```
SELECT sku, search_prod_id 
FROM product p 
WHERE sku not in(SELECT sku FROM price_adjustment  p) 
and sku in (SELECT sku FROM searchable_product s where is_visible = 'T' ) 
and sku in (SELECT sku FROM channel_pricing c where offer_price > 10.00 and offer_price % 2 = 0) 
and sku in (SELECT search_prod_id from product p GROUP BY search_prod_id HAVING count(*) = 1 ) limit 5;
```

Comment: I've just ran that but all the seach_prod_id are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that when doing

```
sku in (SELECT distinct search_prod_id from product p )
```

you are adding to the query sku values which are equal to search_prod_id.
I think that the query you are looking for is this one:

```
SELECT distinct sku, search_prod_id  FROM product p where sku not in(SELECT sku FROM price_adjustment p) and sku in (SELECT sku FROM searchable_product s where is_visible = 'T') and sku in (SELECT sku FROM channel_pricing c where offer_price > 10.00 and offer_price % 2 = 0) limit 5;
```

Comment: That also just returns the same search_prod_id 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

In the last statement `(where .. and sku in (SELECT distinct search_prod_id ...` you select only the sku's which are equal to the search_prod_id. I think you will need something like `where ... and search_prod_id in (SELECT distinct search_prod_id from product ...`

I think this should work:

```
SELECT sku, search_prod_id FROM product p where sku 
not in(SELECT sku FROM price_adjustment p) and sku 
in (SELECT sku FROM searchable_product s 
where is_visible = 'T') and sku in 
(SELECT sku FROM channel_pricing c 
where offer_price > 10.00 and offer_price % 2 = 0) and search_prod_id 
in (SELECT distinct search_prod_id from product p ) limit 5;
```

Comment: This is also returning the same search product id multiple times.